# One line answers

Tags: discussion, answers

Is a one line "mini answer", which actually *does* answer a question to be considered faulty? Should it always be posted as a comment, in order not to be closed?

Comment: If it actually answers the question, I don't see why it should be a comment. Do you have an example of where an answer has been incorrectly converted to a comment?

Comment: Ironically, a short answer here would be completely justified given how this question is itself so short.

Comment: Well, funnily, this question might be answered using a single word: **NO**. But SO requires a minimum length in answers... ;)

Comment: One line is fine.

Comment: Why would you answer a question in a comment anyway? An answer is an answer and a comment is a comment. Which is which shouldn't be determined by length at all.

Comment: I have the strange feeling that a one line answer would immediately be flagged as a Low Quality post.

Comment: If it is a one line answer that is not very good or not very complete, then that might very well happen. A one line answer is not always good. Or even: a one line answer is *rarely* good.

Comment: I think it all depends on how much communicative you are.

Comment: There might be a question mark on the quality of the question, though.

Comment: Good example of [one-liner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1128728/2587435). People seem to dig it. At least 794 people did ;-)

Comment: *"Why would you answer a question in a comment anyway?"* Sometimes I don't have enough time for more than a few words. I might point the way in a comment, and leave it to lower-rep users (who are always asking on meta how to gain rep) to write up a more complete answer. I'm sure I've given a few one-line answers as answers, too. I usually have a reason. I don't recall the reasons.

Comment: @peeskillet, I dig it too.

Comment: Another example of a 1 liner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787321/javascript-not-changing-html-background-color-persistenly/24787431#comment38477179_24787431 at the bottom. Downvoted. IMO it answered it adequately but no one liked it still.

Comment: __Terseness should be appreciated.__

Comment: @peeskillet I would actually call that a bad answer. It doesn't include a link to the method, it doesn't explicitly state the syntax, it doesn't say whether it uses `==` or `.equals`, and it doesn't say that it does not work on primitives. Given the canonicalness of the question, it _should_ have all those things.

Comment: Every reasonable answer to a perl question should be limited to a single line. If not, you just didn't care enough making it shorter.

Comment: Like 9 of 10 times, when I have a question, the perfect answer is a one-liner.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel As we use to say in Italy, "to a good understanding person, a few words are enough". OR, at least, they *should* be enough. Too many imes, though, I see people flagging (when not even downvoting) good answers just because of their shortness...

Comment: @KlingKlang Well.. When I move the cursor over the downvote Button, I see: "This unswer is not usefull". I don't see: "This unswer is too short". People can downvote a post for many "wrong" reasons.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

An answer is an answer. Even if one line is *enough*.

Comment: It will still show up in the LQQ however

Comment: I love that this is a one line answer.

Comment: A sentence is sufficient.

Comment: but what is we explain that answer for further help like giving examples

Answer (score 47):

No.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Fantastic! But in comments I still have to enter at least 15 chars... are we allowed to give a single word answer? weird!

Comment: @Frank No.​​​​​

Comment: That's not a line. That's barely a syllable.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I can't enter a comment shorter than 15 chars. Funny.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Even better!

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: So, where are the cops taking you? ;) Though I like `...` better myself.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Virtual jail, for making useless virtual answers. (I honestly was expecting this answer to get a negative score.)

Comment: @canon :)​​​​​​

Comment: How did you make a one-word answer?

Comment: @0x4 Hax.​​​​​​

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat What is this "hax" of which you speak?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Hint: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266954/one-line-answers/266980?noredirect=1#comment68926_266980

Comment: You should really fit two **No`s** in your answer to fully answer the question(s) in one line.

Comment: Let's not draw attention to our hax plz!

Answer (score 12):

While it may happen that a legitimate question can be answered in one line, most of the time this indicates a **simple typographical error** in the OP's code.

If your possible answer is something more than:

- you have unbalanced brackets/apostrophes
- you forgot about semicolon
- etc.

feel free to post your answer.

Otherwise vote to close the question, as evidenced by a default close reason on SO:

*"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."*

Comment: What if my answer is one of the above mentioned (which are mostly the ones I'd give), i.e.: "You forgot a semicolon"?

Comment: You should vote to close the question with the reason _"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."_ This is one of the default close reasons on SO.

Comment: ... why? If with a single sentence I could save the user's workday and gain his/her infinite gratitude (...) for the eternity?

Comment: Have you read about what is __on-topic__ and what is __off-topic__ on SO? Apparently not. This kind of problem is clearly described by parser's error message. No need for help from other people. So, OP doesn't show any effort to solve the problem. The question is extremely unlikely to help other users. Such questions are off-topic on SO. This is not a __Fix my code__ site. We are trying to collect and share knowledge here. About gathering OP's _infinite gratitude = reputation_ by giving a trivial solution for a trivial problem. There is a term for this here (not invented by me): rep-whore

Comment: SO, the OP must remain without an answer, OK...

Comment: @FrankN.Stein You won't be alone in joining a fleet of those who prefer to _answer_ that a semicolon is missing.  It's ok.  Some might call you a _repwhore_, though.  Moreover, think about it -- it'd really add to a lot of knowledge if there were a dozen questions about errors in a 4 liner _hello world_ C program with such errors.  What an effort to improve human understanding at large!

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Just comment and *then* vote to close: don't mine rep from a simple answer. Simple fixes like that are usually better placed in comments, anyway.

Comment: This answer is tl;dr.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein  No, you shouldn't close the question until you've let the world and the OP know that it is a typo problem.  You're the one who found the problem, so you deserve the rep.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo, many languages and environments (like VBA) don't give comprehensive messages.  Gaining rep for helping people is what this site is about.

Comment: @LanceRoberts This is nonsense. First: Language never gives error messages on it's own. Second: Every modern editor hunts for syntax errors on the fly. _(I hope someone is going to develop a good editor for EMACS :D :D :D)_ Even famous `if(x=0)` is marked as _possible typo_.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo, _There are more things in heaven and earth, Than are dreamt of in your philosophy._ I hope you never have to work with VBA, it will be a traumatic experience for you.

Comment: @LanceRoberts __No! Full stop!__ A programming language grammar is a set of well defined rules describing what can be parsed and translated to a sequence of instructions understandable and executable for a machine (physical, virtual, runtime environment - doesn't matter). Can't find a tool which hunts for syntax errors and typos in VBA? Create one (maybe in some more developer-friendly technology) if these kinds of errors make programming in VBA _a traumatic experience_ for you. Most of your tasks are more challenging than writing parser/lexer/compiler...

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo, I'm happy for you that you have the time to create the tools you need.  I've been programming for over 30 years (since Apple II+s) and I've seen plenty of bad environments.  Hopefully you will always have good environments or the time to make them.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

An answer should never be posted as a comment.

Comment: But wait...is this a comment posted as an answer?

Comment: There are many good reasons to post an answer as a comment.