# Is there such thing as an answer that is too simple?

Tags: discussion, answers

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344811/php-table-background-color-based-on-variable#28344908) today.

In case it one day gets deleted, the question was:

> what is wrong with the following code:
>
> ```
> if($AlarmValue = "OK" )
>      {echo "<tr bgcolor='#FF9999'>";}
> else  
>     {echo "<tr bgcolor='blue'>";}
> ```

The answer of course is simply that the if statement needs a `==`.

I decided that this was so simple, that I just wrote the answer in a comment. There were no other answers and it may have been a typo.

Suddenly, there was an answer that was 1 line that was basically what I had said. Then another answer which was the same thing but with a little more detail.

These both got multiple upvotes.

I know there is more to SO than rep points, but I am sure that on another day, simple questions with simple answers all get downvoted. These were rep points that I could have had.

Is there such thing an answer that is too simple and should just be in the comments?

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answer is the best answer.

Comment: There is a close reason for typos, which I chose to use here. Some people argue that it's only a typo if OP actually knows the difference (meaning they think if OP is absolutely clueless, we should not close the question but answer it), but IMO that's a useless distinction - at the end of the day, it's a crap question that's not particularily useful for anybody else (especially because people who don't know the difference between = and == probably don't know how to search for their issue either) and thus deserves to be closed and deleted.

Comment: I've had the same happen to me more than once. Answer was so trivial that I stuck it in as a comment and then not long after an answer popped up that was basically exactly what I said.

Comment: @MattBurland What do you expect? You can't mark a comment as the accepted answer.

Comment: @mason:  The answer is trivial because the question is trivial and should be closed. It doesn't make sense to write a answer of `Use == instead of =` and it's not worth the time to explain what should be *very, very* basic concepts.

Comment: @MattBurland What is a basic concept to you might take a little explanation for someone new to programming, which is the exact kind of person that would probably ask that question.

Comment: @mason: But we are talking about something that should have been learnt in the very first lesson or tutorial.

Comment: @MattBurland I fail to see how that's relevant. People don't absorb 100% of information. Sometimes they don't remember, or they didn't understand the concept. SO is a Q&A site for programmers, and that is a common programming mistake for new programmers that might require a little explanation. Just because you're experienced and know to watch out for that kind of problem doesn't mean that everyone does, and you shouldn't just dismiss their problems for that reason alone. It's a valid question, it deserves a valid answer (or more likely be closed as a duplicate for such a common thing).

Comment: @MattBurland To elaborate on why it's important to properly answer trivial questions, think about NullReferenceExceptions. You and I know what they are and how to avoid them. And you'd think that'd be something basic that a new programmer would learn early on. But that's not always the case. Therefore, there should be a well explained definitive answer that covers the situation. And it exists, in John Saunder's excellent [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142), which has been viewed 116,206 times.

Comment: @mason: But you are also missing the point that any `NullReferenceException` question will probably be closed as a dupe. The question the OP highlights probably has a dupe somewhere as well. So again, there's really no point answering it. It should be closed and eventually deleted. But if somebody can answer it quickly in a comment, it can be less time consuming to just do that than try to find the dupe and doesn't prevent the eventual automatic deletion of the question.

Comment: @MattBurland No, I definitely did not miss that point. I specifically addressed it at the end of my 2nd comment. Just because something is closed as a duplicate doesn't mean it doesn't deserve an answer-it's just that it's *already* been answered, so we need to direct them to a definitive answer for that issue rather than directly answering. So you shouldn't close it *because* it's trivial. You should close it because it's already got an answer. If it's trivial *and* doesn't have an answer, then feel free to answer it yourself, and not just post a comment as you originally suggested.

Comment: @l4mpi I don't know that misunderstanding the difference between the assignment and equality comparison operators is a _typo_.

Comment: The question and its answer may be simple, and it might not have a close reason like typo; but still I don't like these type of questions. Because asker didn't do his homework before asking a question. There are a lot of people answering questions here who learned themselves. Anybody can easily learn the basics of any language on the internet now. And they should do that too, before wasting people's time.

Comment: Related: [One line answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266954/176646)

Comment: Today someone asked a question that I don't know anything about. I just searched his question on duckduckgo, and the first result was his answer. I just posted a comment with the link and said "this was the first result when I searched such and such on duckduckgo." I just hate it when people waste my time.

Comment: If an answer is trivial or there's no way to answer a question completely, I normally just comment. Ironically, the reason you don't bother posting an answer - because you believe the answer is self-evident - is usually the very reason other people get lots of upvotes when they do. Let 'em. If the question is *good* and the answer is nontrivial but still very short, post it as an answer. This is pretty rare, though.

Comment: It is a pretty obvious error. Especially when the compiler puts an angry red squiggly under it and tells you you cant convert a string to a bool. A quick Google search on the proper syntax for an IF statement will usually include examples that show the comparison operator "==". I don't see any problem with stupid questions with easy answers though. If no one ever answered stupid questions then it would be impossible to Google them. Besides, we have all had our derp moments...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Keep in mind that there is a close reason for typos**, which *fits perfectly* for that question. The question appears to be attracting close votes, so the meta effect <del>should take</del> has taken care of it.

These aren't the best questions to answer, as most likely they will be closed (and possibly later deleted) so it's not in your favor to answer it.

> I decided that this was so simple, that I just wrote the answer in a comment.

Users are [encouraged to move answers from comments to answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/359284), so either way adding it as a comment is not the best idea. If nobody had caught the typo, and nobody read your comment, the question would be left without any answers, which is an issue. The question is left on the unanswered questions tab, and you run the risk of future visitors giving up because they didn't bother reading the comments.

Now, that doesn't mean that an answer like

> You need to use == instead of a single one (=).

Is a great answer. **It isn't**, especially in this question where there are two statements using a single `=`, and only one of them is incorrect. You should try to be more specific about it, especially in this case, which is why **a bit of detail will go a long way**.

> but I am sure that on another day, simple questions with simple answers all get downvoted.

Everyone votes differently, and everyone uses different criteria for what is a good and bad answer. I personally will upvote simple answers that get to the point *with the correct answer*, but if it's too ambiguous (like in this case) it might deserve a downvote.

> Is there such thing an answer that is too simple and should just be in the comments?

[No.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/359284)

Comment: "If nobody had caught the typo, and nobody read your comment, the question would be left without any answers, which is a huge issue." - completely disagree. This would not be an issue at all, because the quesiton should be closed and subsequently deleted. On the other hand, _having an upvoted answer_ is a huge issue, as it means the question cannot be auto-deleted by the roomba anymore and thus dilutes the SO search results even more...

Comment: @l4mpi My intention was to relate that to the larger scope of things, where answers should generally not sit in comments. **In this case, it was a bad question and it's being closed like it should be.** Good questions with answers in the comments exist, and we shouldn't be encouraging them.

Comment: It's still not a "huge issue" unless a mod chooses to delete the comment for no reason (which is a way bigger issue IMO).

Comment: Anyone can come along and convert a comment answer to a real answer, i don't see that as a problem. If i know the answer to something but don't have the time (or don't care) to properly formulate a good answer, I'd prefer dropping a hint in a comment instead to let someone else run with it.

Comment: I strongly disagree that this is a typo, at least in the case of an inexperienced programmer. A typo means that you accidentally mistyped something, and is not deliberate. But using the wrong operator shows a basic misunderstanding of how to use the language, and should not be closed as a typo. Instead, it should be answered with an explanation of the difference between the operators. Or, if a similar question exists (which is likely), then it should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 19):

Yes.

Comment: About as useful as the (now deleted) "no!"-*answer*...

Comment: I downvoted this at first, but now I see that it's trying to serve as an example than an answer can be too trivial. Sort of a tautology.

Comment: Simple answer +1 :p

Comment: Beat me to it.   It'd be simpler without the stars.

Comment: @TabAlleman That was almost certainly done to get around the minimum length restriction.

Comment: Ooooh...right.    Hmm, would blank spaces have served as well?

Comment: @TabAlleman No, but you can do [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266980/176646).

Comment: Yep, I was going to say that too. Great^H^H^H^H^H Overly-literal minds think alike.