# Flag comment as answer still disputed?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I flag this 2 answer [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232738/hide-content-inside-iframe/30232800#30232800) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232738/hide-content-inside-iframe/30232835#30232835) both are just single line comment and down voted still it is disputed?

First answer:

> You cannot select a dom element inside a Iframe from the outside of iframe using javascript.

Second answer:

> You can not access the content of iframe for security reason.

I that good answer? Or that answer is useful?

Comment: Only mods can see your flag summary page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bad answers make bad comments. If an answer is unhelpful, then downvote it to indicate that.

Your flags were reviewed by your peers and the consensus was that those were intelligible answers. Again, not necessarily particularly helpful ones, but far short of "severe formatting or content problems".

Comment: But, i think that single line is comment only. And you can see that actually there not that security problem of OP.

Comment: @ketan A one-line answer can be a decent answer. "You can not access the content of iframe for security reason" is not a bad way to answer a question about accessing iframe elements.

Comment: @ketan: If someone asks (at another site) *What will happen if you put your hand over an open flame?", an appropriate answer would be *You get burnt.*. Sometimes a one-lime answer is appropriate for the question. If you ask *Can an OSX application run in MS DOS 5?*, the only possible answer is "No, it can not.". If you want that on multiple lines, I can do so, but it won't change the answer.

Comment: Indeed. See this post: [One line answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266954).

Comment: @PatrickHofman i am not saying it's just single line comment. But it doesn't relate to question also. Or it just says it may be issue of security.

Comment: @KenWhite i am not saying it's just single line comment. But it doesn't relate to question also. Or it just says it may be issue of security.

Comment: @ketan: They *are* (at least *were*) answers. I didn't say they were *good* answers; I certainly would have downvoted them. Just because they're short or terse doesn't mean they're not answers. If you ask "Can an OS X application run in DOS 5?", and I write "Birds fly high" or "OS X is made by Apple.", that's *not an answer*, because it does not make any effort to answer the question asked. If I write "No, it can not.", it *is* an answer, because it answers the question asked. It might answer it very poorly (in which case it should be downvoted), but it addresses the question asked.