# Single line answer with word maybe

Tags: discussion, answers, disputed-flags

I read the question [One line answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266954/one-line-answers) and given answers and comments, still not completely sure about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800783/weird-enum-in-destructor/33800881#33800881) in which OP asks why this seemingly dead code is present and the answer given is "**maybe** it is a trick to [*correct answer here, though without detail*]".

I think this qualifies better for a comment than an answer and raised a "not an answer" flag which ended up disputed.

So my question is: Can a one liner counted as answer which starts with word **maybe, possibly, I guess etc.** for the questions where definitive answers can be given?

Comment: If it's a correct answer, maybe it's better to just edit out the "maybe", "possibly" or "I guess" ?

Comment: @m69 Won't this promote more low quality answer. Instead one can do a little discussion in comment or leave a cue for somebody else to catchup and prepare a good self-contained complete answer.

Comment: Well, at least future readers will not be in doubt about whether it's a good answer or not. It would of course be better to flesh out the answer with more explanation, but that of course requires a lot more work.

Comment: I am not defending the original answer, but the term "may be" may refer to the intent of the code author to use the trick, not the principle of the trick, and I believe the votes would verify the correctness of the answer, even it is not a very good habit for me.

Comment: And I remember "not an answer" refers to users not attempting (at least the context looks not likely) to answer the question, even a wrong, unconfirmed answer is still an answer if it is trying to answer the questions, if it is the case just use votes to indicate it.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, if the answer is correct and it solves the problem described in the question, then it should definitely count as the answer.

The word *maybe* could be added out of deference or humility, when other alternative ways to solve the specified problem are possible, and also in the event that the solution proposed by the author has not been personally verified.

In the latter case, the author cannot be 100% sure of its correctness, compliance with syntax, etc. But such an answer can be useful in that it will lead to a solution to the problem.